# Moodle tour box in the wrong position

Tags: moodle

friends.

I am trying to build a Moodle tour using selector, however I faced a problem that let me stuck.

Help box appears much beneath the the selector target.

Here two snapshots that show setup and the problem:

setup screen:
[image]

panel screen:
[image]

It should be pointing to 'meus cursos'.

Any clue?

I thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend trying to point the tour boxes at CSS selectors that are relatively positioned according to something else.  For instance these FA icons.  I would always recommend instead targeting them at the list item, instead.  Inspect the text element, and see if you can find a particular class or ID for that which can be used.

Comment: I did, but there is not such particular CLASS or ID. And it does not work with element:nth-child(x)

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the backdrop: it might not be compatible with that CSS selector.